# How to fox laravel migration error "General error: 1005 Can't create table"

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

When I try to run migrations to create foreign key constraints I get the following error in my command prompt. I need help to overcome it as i searched a lot on the internet and tried many previous answers of same type question, unfortunately, none has worked

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `db_blog`.`category_posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `category_posts` add constraint `category_posts_post_id_foreign` foreign key (`post_id`) references `posts` (`id`) on delete cascade) at 
>    1
>
> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `db_blog`.`category_posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

Please use the argument -v to see more details.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')- 
    >onDelete('cascade');


            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I do not understand where there is a problem in this area

Comment: What type of column is `posts.id`? In the post-table.

Comment: in posts table post id type 'bigint'

Comment: Then `post_id` in `category_posts` needs to be of `bigint` too. Types of columns needs to be of a match.

Comment: i try with 'integer'  type and also 'increments' in laravel but does not  work

Comment: The conditions for creating foreign keys are defined here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html . AND please add table definition for posts

Comment: If `posts.id` is a `bigint` (signed) then `category_posts.post_id` must be bigint (signed). So they must be of the same sign, length *and* type. Exactly the same.

Comment: @Qirel brother, i try this but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which version of your project, but in the latest ones, bigInteger is used in the foreign key, and for the ID, bigIncrements is used.

I also believe that the post table is being created first rather than the category_posts. Otherwise, have it first created.
Can you confirm if this would be it?

Comment: i think you asr right when i migrate post table before category_post.This is the image of migration  https://photos.app.goo.gl/PiZBbWpQCEuSv8Az8

Comment: To change the order you could rename the file, or just create another migration. Normally, i change the name. More specifically the creation date...

Comment: brother i create a new migration for post, but i get the same error.

Comment: If possible, show how the two migrations are, just like you print from the directory. I would like to see the way they are relating. Or just paste the code here